# Trigger 'oninvalid' event on input field

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have been looking into `oninvalid` attribute of HTML5 but can't find much documentation on it. As of now in my testing I have found that it only fires when a submit button (`<input type="submit"/>`) is clicked and value in it is not valid (like it has `required` attribute and value is empty).

Is there any way by which I can trigger the event to validate the value in field which in turn would fire `oninvalid` event if invalid value is present?

Comment: May be related: [**How _HTML5_ checks if data is valid**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#Constraint_Validation)

Answer (score 2):

something like this should make things clearer:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input id="myInput" required />
    <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
</form>

<script>

var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
var form = document.getElementByid("myForm"); 

//attach event to fire on invalid:
input.addEventListener("invalid", function(){
    console.log("invalid element!");
});

//when one of these is called, the invalid event will be triggered
//(providing the input is left empty, since there is a required on it):
input.checkValidity();
form.checkValidity();


</script>
```

Either calling checkValidity() on the input element (or enclosing form) or clicking the form submit button when the input is in an invalid state will fire the invalid handler I attached and log the message to console.

It appears as if it is not fired when the user enters a value into the input, despite the validity of the input changing (which IMO would have been pretty damn useful!)

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/invalid :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears the method you are looking for is [`reportValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity).

You can call it on a whole form or on just one input.

```html
<form id=myForm>
    <input id=myInput required />
</form><br>
<button onclick="myForm.reportValidity()">Form Validity</button><br>
<button onclick="myInput.reportValidity()">Input Validity</button>
```

You can call [`checkValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity) if you don't want to report to the user that the value is invalid.

Both methods will activate the [oninvalid event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/invalid) if the value is invalid.